# Package Hibernate does not exist when the package is added

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

Why do I get an error? When I run Maven compile I get errors package org.hibernate does not exist, but I add Hibernate to lib. [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylu4v.jpg)

Comment: There some possibility. check your maven setting.xml file. it is possible you can not fetch hibernate jar file from repository. make sure that your repository has hibernate version jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining in your project a `lib` directory and adding it in the classpath within your editor is not really how Maven works. [Take a look at the Dependency Mechanism in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). In short you have to define the dependency coordinates in the Maven POM file and Maven will take care of the rest.